# How to set the correct typescript type for setValue in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I want to pass the function `setValue()` down to a child component. Then I get the following error message:

```
Type 'UseFormSetValue<Inputs>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormSetValue<Record<string, any>>'
```

[image]

How can I pass down the function correctly?

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-wohwk?file=/src/index.tsx)

```
function App() {
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
  } = useForm<Inputs>({
  });

  return (
    <form>
      <Field2 setValue={setValue} register={register} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `UseFormReturn["setValue"]` type resolves to `UseFormSetValue<Record<string, any>>`. You can explicitly configure the `setValue` type to use the correct generic params like this:

```
setValue: UseFormSetValue<Inputs>;
```

Instead of:

```
setValue: UseFormReturn["setValue"];
```

Note: All public types can be imported from `react-hook-form` module

```
import {
  UseFormReturn,
  UseFormSetValue
} from "react-hook-form";
```

### Live Demo

I also fixed your related type error in register props in the live demo (`UseFormRegister<Inputs>` instead of `UseFormReturn['register']`

[image: Edit 67285413/how-to-set-correct-typescript-type-for-setvalue-in-react-hook-form]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is great!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended type for set value is FieldValues, we can also define custom type or any.

```
import { UseFormSetValue, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form"
```

In code

```
 setValue?: UseFormSetValue<FieldValues>
```